# How to extract all .mp4 with youtube-dl in Python?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm trying to write a Python script that can extract the download link of any video in .mp4 file format. For this I'm using `youtube-dl` but it returns the video link in .m3u8 file format. How can I get them in .mp4 file format?

Comment: I guess you need to convert it into the mp4 format.

Answer (score 6):

format mp4 code:

- 137: 1080p
- 136: 720p
- 135: 480p
- 134: 360p
- 133: 240p

  ```
  import youtube_dl

  url = 'https://twitter.com/PassengersMovie/status/821025484150423557'

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format':'137'}) as ydl:
      ydl.download([url])
  ```

Comment: What if I want to extract all .mp4 formats available for download.

Comment: add loop in code for example `for f in range(3, 8): with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format':'13' + str(f)}) as ydl: ...`

Comment: Above answer not working as of 14.02.21 with latest Linut Mint apt-install (downloads version 2016.02.22 - "YouTube said: Invalid parameters"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following scripts and edit `download_list` only.

```
import youtube_dl
from enum import Enum


class YLFormat(Enum):
    m4a = '140'  # audio only
    mp4_144p = '160'
    mp4_240p = '133'
    mp4_360p = '134'
    mp4_480p = '135'
    mp4_720p = '136'
    mp4_1080p = '137'
    gp3_176_144 = '17'  # 3gp: 176*144
    gp3_320_240 = '36'
    flv = '5'
    webm = '43'
    mp4_640_360 = '18'  # 640 * 360
    mp4_1280_720 = '22'


def download(url: str, options: dict):
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])


download_list = [  # edit this
    ('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbttZVTSJRU', YLFormat.mp4_640_360, YLFormat.mp4_1280_720, ...),
]

for cur_data in download_list:
    cur_url, tuple_format = cur_data[0], cur_data[1:]
    for format_info in tuple_format:
        if not isinstance(format_info, YLFormat):
            print(f'the format is not correct. format: {format_info}')
            continue
        fmt_name, fmt = format_info.name, format_info.value
        try:
            download(cur_url, dict(format=fmt,
                                   outtmpl=f'%(title)s-{fmt_name}.%(ext)s',
                                   # ignoreerrors=True,
                                   # quiet=True
                                   ))
        except youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError:
            print(f'download error: {cur_url} | {fmt_name}')
```

Comment: Above answer not working as of 14.02.21 with latest Linut Mint apt-install (downloads version 2016.02.22 - The actual terminal output is 'the format is not correct. format: {format_info}' so not sure about the format_info parameter

Comment: @Hektor You should read the answer clearly, I say **edit** ``download_list``, so if you just copy and paste, please remove ``...`` from ``download_list``.

Comment: I try and update youtube-dl, and then rerun it still OK. (OS: ``Windows 10``, youtube-dl version: ``2021.02.10``, Python: ``3.7.4``)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had to download the latest version of youtube-dl as the Mint repositories are apparently 5 years out of date.