# YouTube-DL Python output file format not mp4

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-dl

I have written a small piece of code in python to extract either the audio or the video from a YouTube video. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

link = input("Enter the video link:")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter a for audio file, v for video file:")
    if choice == "a" or choice == "v":
        break

ydl_opts = {}

if choice == "a":
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info_dict = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)

if choice == "a":
    path = f'D:\\DwnldsYT\\{video_title}.mp3'
if choice == "v":
    path = f'D:\\DwnldsYT\\{video_title}.mp4'

ydl_opts.update({'outtmpl':path})

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

The audio extraction works fine, but the problem is with the video extraction. When I extract the video, I am getting the output as an mkv file, not an mp4 file. Any idea about how to save the video file as mp4?

Comment: I think you can find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870658/how-to-extract-all-mp4-with-youtube-dl-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the video quality is above 1080p it can't be downloaded as MP4, try downloading video of max resolution 720p or 1080p to check if it's still downloading as mkv

Comment: The max res that I can download as mp4 is 480p. Is there any way to download 1080p videos as mp4?

Comment: Try this
`
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'format':'137'}) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
`
As mentioned by @ thekid77777 see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870658/how-to-extract-all-mp4-with-youtube-dl-in-python

Comment: It works. Thx! But I face another problem. Previously, both the audio and the video of the  YT vid was getting downloaded. But now, only the vid is getting downloaded. Is there any way to download both the audio and the vid at 1080p as an mp4 file?

Comment: And another thing. If the max res of the YT vid is 720p or 480p, then my code throws me an error. Is there any way to identify the best video res and download my vid as an mp4 in that res?

Comment: I had the same issue but for videos better than 1080p, when I researched about it found out that's the way that youtube dl works, try using pytube, irrespective here's my code made using youtube dl(for reference), https://github.com/SumukhJadhav/Python-Automation/blob/master/YoutubeDownloader.py